# Autocomplete in TeXworks editor on TeX Live

Tags: texlive, texworks, auto-completion

1. How I can enable autocomplete option in TeXworks Editor (texlive-win.OS) for latex command, i.e., when I type `\incl` it automatically shows `\includgraphics[]{}` or when i type `\begin{fi` it can show (and so type) `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` automatically.
   Please tell me step by step.
2. I have a thesis file which in main doc.
   It includes some `\include{chpa}` command.
   How i can enable structure of file in the left of the texwork window?

I have read some question in this forum but they were not well. Please say me step by step.

Comment: The format of this site is more suited to asking one question at a time. You should most probably remove the second question and add it as a new question to this site.

Comment: Could there be any help for MacOS? I'm using TeXWorks (Version 0.6.8 ("github") [r.6b1c6ab, ]) with MacTex-2023 distribution in macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. Enabling autocompletion in TeXWorks preference does not work. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This feature (autocompletion) should be the default feature. To ensure it, go to `Edit` → `Preferences`. In the `editor` tab of the window that opens autocompletion (under global editor options) should have been checked like this:

[image]

Then read this:

[image]

This is available under the help menu - A short manual for TeXworks. All you have to do is type `bfig` and press  <kbd>TAB</kbd>  to get

```
\begin{figure}

\end{figure}•
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd>  is the key that enables auto completion.